# Right way to decrypt RSA session key

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I'm using pycryptodomex for RSA encryption, decryption. 
[Im following this article](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html)

```
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

file_in = open("encrypted_data.bin", "rb")

private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private.pem").read())

enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = \
   [ file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1) ]

# Decrypt the session key with the public RSA key
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)

# Decrypt the data with the AES session key
cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
data = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
```

It is showing following error

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        11 # Decrypt the session key with the public RSA key
>        12 cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
>   ---> 13 session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)
>        14 
>        15 # Decrypt the data with the AES session key
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py
>   in decrypt(self, ciphertext)
>       165         # Step 1b and 1c
>       166         if len(ciphertext) != k or k 167             raise ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length.")
>       168         # Step 2a (O2SIP)
>       169         ct_int = bytes_to_long(ciphertext)
>
> ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.

Is there any problem in Code  ?

Comment: pls read this doc on using PKCS for encryption/decryption, the error you're seeing is in here. Here's the [link](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/pkcs1_v1_5.html)

Comment: More likely a problem with the input or input / key combination. BTW, please fix your comments when copying: "Decrypt the session key with the public RSA key".

Comment: What makes you think you have the correct private key?

Comment: I followed the article which I specified in the question. Is it requires padding removal or text conversion ?

Comment: Do you know the padding that was used during encryption?

Comment: See attached link